# Selenium testing using C#: assertions. Why am I getting the following error?

Tags: c#, selenium, assertions

using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Threading;
    using Selenium;

```
namespace Search1
{
  [TestClass]
  public class SearchTest1
  {
    public SearchTest1()
    {

    }

    private TestContext testContextInstance;

    /// <summary>
    ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
    ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
    ///</summary>
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }

    private ISelenium selenium;

    [TestMethod]
    public void SearchMethod1()
    {

selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://localhost/crm.aspx");
        selenium.Start();
        selenium.Open("/crm/SearchPage.aspx?function=3");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        Assert.IsTrue(selenium.IsTextPresent("Select All  |  Clear All"));
        try
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(selenium.IsTextPresent("Select All  |  Clear All"));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
 selenium.Click("//span[@onclick=\"fnCheckGroupWithMessage('You have selected all items.', 'cbxRepeater_');\"]");
        Assert.AreEqual("'You have selected all items.", selenium.GetAlert());

        decimal totalCheckboxes = selenium.GetXpathCount("//input[@type='checkbox']");

        for (int i = 1; i < totalCheckboxes + 1; i++) 
        { 
            Assert.IsTrue(selenium.IsChecked("//input[@type='checkbox'][" + i + "]")); 
        }

    }
 }
}
```

Test method Search1.SearchTest1.SearchMethod1 threw exception: 
Selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element //input[@type='checkbox'][2] not found

Comment: Think it might be an index problem? You're starting at 1, index may start at 0?

Comment: XPath starts array indexing at 1 so the starting condition should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this instead of `selenium.IsChecked("//input[@type='checkbox'][" + i + "]")`:

```
selenium.IsChecked("/descendant-or-self::input[@type='checkbox'][" + i + "]")
```

Comment: thanks Wesley! But I haven't been able to test if the code you gave me is working because something else broke before it. I will let you know after I fix this one first.